# galois extension of imaginary quadratic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field, and let $K \subset L$ be a Galois extension. Let $\tau$ denote complex conjugation. Show that $L$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $\tau(L)=L$.

My apologies for this basic question. I tried to exploit the Galois correspondence.

===

On the one hand, I have

$1 \subset Gal(K / \mathbb{Q}) \subset Gal(L/ \mathbb{Q})$

which corresponds to

$L \supset \mathbb{Q} \supset \mathbb{Q}$

but this leads me nowhere.

Comment: $L$ is not contained in $Q$.

Comment: Your first line of inclusions makes no sense, @user

Comment: ..and the second one is not very interesting, is it?

Comment: My first post (+ first edit) was wrong. It is fixed now.

Comment: I think I am going down the wrong path because I confuse $< \tau > \subset \ Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ with $< \tau > = Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$; where the last $\tau: K \to K$ and the first $\tau: L \to L$.

Comment: $\tau(L)=L$ implies $|{\rm Gal}(L:{\mathbb Q})| > |{\rm Gal}(L:K)| = |L:K|$ and, since $|K:{\mathbb Q}|=2$, we must have $|{\rm Gal}(L:{\mathbb Q})| = |L:{\mathbb Q}|$, so $L:{\mathbb Q}$ is Galois.